# get all the Issues under a Version in JIRA

Tags: jira-rest-api, python-jira

I have a few issues under a Version ID: "12345" and Version Name:"ABCD". I need the list of all Issues under this version or list of Unresolved Issues ID.

My code to get all the version:

```
jira = JIRA(options={'server': 'address', 'verify':'/path/to/ca.crt'}, basic_auth=("usrName","password"))
jra = jira.project('NAME')
versions = jira.project_versions(jra)
print(jira.version_count_unresolved_issues(VersionID) )
```

After this i need the IssueID or the name of Issues under the Particular Version. Using `jira.version_count_unresolved_issues(projID)` i can get number of unresolved issues. But not the name or IssueID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future :
     `ver_isse_count = jira.version_count_related_issues(VersionID)
      # getting the number of Issues under that Version
      ver_un_isse_count = jira.version_count_unresolved_issues(VerID)
      #getting the number of unresolved Issues under that version`

```
query = jira.search_issues(        
jql_str="project=NAME AND fixVersion=TYPE AND resolution=Unresolved"
)    

for i in query:        
   print(i.id , '\t' , i.key)
   issue_key = i.key
```